# Get selected object from ListBox (binded to ListStore) in Python GTK

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, pygobject

I have made a simple GTK music player with ListBox (as playlist).

This is GObject class, which i use to bind to ListBox (using bind_model() method) and ListStore.

```
import eyed3
from gi.repository import Gio, GObject

class Song(GObject.GObject):

    path = GObject.Property(type=str)
    name = GObject.Property(type=str)

    def __init__(self, path):
        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)
        self.path = path
        self.file = eyed3.load(path)
        self.name = self

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file.tag.artist) + ' - ' + str(self.file.tag.title)


playlist = Gio.ListStore().new(Song)
```

And this is how I bind ListStore to ListBox:

```
play_listbox.connect('row-selected', self.on_row_selected)

playlist.append(Song('/home/user/Downloads/Some album/01 - Song1.mp3'))
playlist.append(Song('/home/user/Downloads/Some album/02 - Song2.mp3'))

play_listbox.bind_model(playlist, self.create_song_label)

def create_song_label(self, song):
    return Gtk.Label(label=song.name)
```

And so far, everything works like it should.

**The question is: Is it possible to retrieve Song object (stored in playlist) based on selection? To retrieve path property stored in that object?**

If not, is it possible to at least retrieve selection text? Trying this with

```
def on_row_selected(self, container, row):
    print(row.widget.label)
```

Gives a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/App/player.py", line 45, in on_row_selected
    print(row.widget.label) # or data, value, text - nothing works
RuntimeError: unable to get the value
```

row variable is of type

```
<Gtk.ListBoxRow object at 0x7f9fe7604a68 (GtkListBoxRow at 0x5581a51ef7d0)>
```

So above code, I think, should work like a charm... but it doesn't.

Thank you very much for any help provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to assign the selection with:

```
treeview_selection = treeview.get_selection()
```

And connect it with the 'changed' signal:

```
treeview_selection.connect('changed', on_tree_selection_changed)
```

Then you can fetch the required data with:

```
def on_tree_selection_changed(self, treeview):
    model, treeiter = treeview.get_selected()
    if treeiter is not None:
        print(model[treeiter][0]) # you should a list index to get the data you require for each row - first column = [0], second column = [1] etc.
```

I would suggest you read the [pgi docs](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/) and also the [python Gtk docs](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Is it possible to have hidden properties? For example, I don't want to have song paths displayed in TreeView, but I need to extract them whenever I select a song.

Comment: personally i would use some kind of storage for that - i use sqlite3 databases and sqlalchemy for simple storage then you would query the database using the song title from the selection. if you need i can add a simple way to do this in my answer?

Comment: you use a pickle file or another database or even tinydb https://pypi.org/project/tinydb/  but the idea will always be the same.. use the treeview selection to query your storage for all the info stored for that song, that way you can store lots of other info about  song - file path, album art, lyrics, online links, whatever you need to store for the song essentially

Comment: also if my answer has answered your initial question please dont forget to mark as accepted

Comment: Well, that's some way to do it. Thanks :) P.S. That's the best strain out there :P

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to retrieve Song object (stored in playlist) based on selection? To retrieve path property stored in that object?

```
def on_row_selected(self, container, row):
    song = playlist.get_item(row.get_index())
```

> If not, is it possible to at least retrieve selection text?

```
def on_row_selected(self, container, row):
    name = row.get_child().get_text()
```

Here is an example. You could also use the `selected-rows-changed` signal if you have to deal with multiple selections:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio, GObject
import sys

class Song(GObject.GObject):

    path = GObject.Property(type=str)
    name = GObject.Property(type=str)

    def __init__(self, path, name):
        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)
        self.path = path
        self.name = name
class GUI:

    def __init__(self):        
        self.playlist = Gio.ListStore()
        self.playlist.append(Song("path1", "name1"))
        self.playlist.append(Song("path2", "name2"))
        self.playlist.append(Song("path3", "name3"))

        play_listbox = Gtk.ListBox()
        play_listbox.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.SINGLE)
        play_listbox.bind_model(self.playlist, self.create_widget_func)
        play_listbox.connect('row-selected', self.on_row_selected_1)
        play_listbox.connect('row-selected', self.on_row_selected_2)
        play_listbox.connect('selected-rows-changed', self.on_selected_rows_changed)

        window = Gtk.Window()
        window.add(play_listbox)
        window.connect("destroy", self.on_window_destroy)
        window.show_all()

    def create_widget_func(self, song):
        return Gtk.Label(label = song.name)

    def on_row_selected_1(self ,container, row):
        print("on_row_selected_1")
        song = self.playlist.get_item(row.get_index())
        print(song.path)

    def on_row_selected_2(self ,container, row):
        print("on_row_selected_2")
        print(row.get_child().get_text())

    def on_selected_rows_changed(self, container):      
        print("on_selected_rows_changed", len(container.get_selected_rows()), "item(s) selected")
        for row in container.get_selected_rows():
            song = self.playlist.get_item(row.get_index())
            print(song.name, song.path)
        print("---")

    def on_window_destroy(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()

def main():

    app = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```